# how to filter data with multiple buttons using delegate?

Tags: swift, string, uitableview, uibutton, delegates

The Delegate that I am using is used to filter out the specified category using a delegate when a button is pressed in the FilterVC

what im struggling with is setting up buttons in the FilterVC so that filter works in the HomeVC

ive noticed that issue might be in my FilterVC when using the delegate in the `@IBAction func acceptSelections` where im getting the error Cannot convert value of type 'RoundButton?' to expected argument type 'String?' when calling the buttons when using the delegate to control which category

[image: screens]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var activeFiltersStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var stackViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var jewelryFilterLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var hatFilterLbl: UILabel!   
    @IBOutlet var shoeFilterLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var apparelFilterLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var gearFilterLbl: UILabel!

    private lazy var baseQuery: Query = {
      return Firestore.firestore().collection("products").limit(to: 50)
    }()

    fileprivate var query: Query?

    lazy private var filters: (navigationController: UINavigationController,
                           filtersController: FilterViewController) = {
          return FilterViewController.fromStoryboard(delegate: self)
    }()

    @IBAction func didTapClearBtn(_ sender: Any){
        filters.filtersController.clearFilters()
        controller(filters.filtersController, didSelectCategory: nil, sativa: nil, indica: nil, hybrid: nil, gear: nil)
    }

    var productSetup: [ProductList] = []
    var products: ProductList?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // arranges products by store nearest you
        fetchProducts { (products) in
            self.productSetup = products.sorted(by: { $0.itemName < $1.itemName })
            self.productListTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // fetches Firebase Data
    func fetchProducts(_ completion: @escaping ([ProductList]) -> Void) {
        let productQuery = Firestore.firestore().collection("products").limit(to: 50)
        productQuery.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot, !snapshot.isEmpty else {
                return
            }
            completion(snapshot.documents.compactMap( {ProductList(dictionary: $0.data())} ))
        }
        // shows Firestore data in log (not neccessary code just used to be seen in logs)
        productQuery.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Oh no! Got an error! \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
            let allDocuments = snapshot.documents
            for productDocument in allDocuments {
                print("I have this product \(productDocument.data())")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return productSetup.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell") as?
        HomeCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.configure(withProduct: productSetup[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

}

extension HomeViewController: FiltersViewControllerDelegate{
    func query(withCategory jewelry: String?, hat: String?, shoe: String?, gear: String?, apparel: String?) -> Query {

      if jewelry == nil && hat == nil && shoe == nil && gear == nil && apparel == nil {
          stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
          activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = true
      } else {
          stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 44
          activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = false
      }

      var filtered = baseQuery

      // Sort and Filter data

      if let jewelry = jewelry, !jewelry.isEmpty {
          filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: jewelry)
      }

      if let hat = hat, ! hat.isEmpty {
          filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: hat)
      }

      if let shoe = shoe, !shoe.isEmpty {
          filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: shoe)
      }

      if let gear = gear, !gear.isEmpty {
          filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: gear)
      }

      if let apparel = apparel, !apparel.isEmpty {
          filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: apparel)
      }

      return filtered
  }

  func controller(_ controller: FilterViewController,
                  didSelectCategory jewelry: String?,
                  hat: String?,
                  shoe: String?,
                  gear: String?,
                  apparel: String?) {

        if jewelry == nil && hat == nil && shoe == nil && gear == nil && apparel == nil {
            stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 44
            activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = false
        }

        let filtered = query(withCategory: jewelry, hat: hat, shoe: shoe, gear: gear, apparel: apparel)

        if let jewelry = jewelry, ! jewelry.isEmpty {
            jewelryFilterLbl.text = jewelry
            jewelryFilterLbl.isHidden = false
        } else {
            jewelryFilterLbl.isHidden = true
        }

        if let hat = hat, ! hat.isEmpty {
            hatFilterLbl.text = hat
            hatFilterLbl.isHidden = false
        } else {
            hatFilterLbl.isHidden = true
        }

        if let shoe = shoe, ! shoe.isEmpty {
            shoeFilterLbl.text = shoe
            shoeFilterLbl.isHidden = false
        } else {
            shoeFilterLbl.isHidden = true
        }

        if let gear = gear, !gear.isEmpty {
            gearFilterLbl.text = gear
            gearFilterLbl.isHidden = false
        } else {
            gearFilterLbl.isHidden = true
        }

        if let apparel = apparel, ! apparel.isEmpty {
            apparelFilterLbl.text = apparel
            apparelFilterLbl.isHidden = false
        } else {
            apparelFilterLbl.isHidden = true
        }

        query = filtered
    }

}
```

---

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol FiltersViewControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
  func controller(_ controller: FilterViewController,
                  didSelectCategory jewelry: String?,
                  hat: String?,
                  shoe: String?,
                  gear: String?,
                  apparel: String?)
}

class FilterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var jewelryBtn: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var hatBtn: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var shoeBtn: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var gearBtn: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var apparelBtn: RoundButton!

    static func fromStoryboard(delegate: FiltersViewControllerDelegate? = nil) ->
    (navigationController: UINavigationController, filtersController: FilterViewController) {
      let navController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FiltersViewController")
      as! UINavigationController
      let controller = navController.viewControllers[0] as! FilterViewController
      controller.delegate = delegate
      return (navigationController: navController, filtersController: controller)
    }

    weak var delegate: FiltersViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func filterSelect(_ sender: Any) {
        if let button : UIButton = sender as? UIButton
        {
            button.isSelected = !button.isSelected

            if (button.isSelected)
            {
                button.backgroundColor = .green
            }
            else
            {
                button.backgroundColor = .gray
            }
        }
    }

    func clearFilters() {
        apparelBtn.isSelected = false
        jewelryBtn.isSelected = false
        shoeBtn.isSelected = false
        hatBtn.isSelected = false
        gearBtn.isSelected = false
    }

    @IBAction func closeFilter(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func acceptSelections(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.controller(self,                          //Problem integrating the buttons to get the correct category
                             didSelectCategory: jewelryBtn,
                             hat: hatBtn,
                             shoe: shoeBtn,
                             gear: gearBtn,
                             apparel: apparelBtn)
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You defined your method signature to expect optional strings but your are passing button objects

Comment: Suggestion: fewer uses of the word "controller" would help readability.

Comment: Why are you sending the entire view controller (FilterViewController) to HomeViewController, Miss San Diego?  There's no point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the filter functionality is pure boolean I recommend to just return the `isSelected` values of the buttons

```
protocol FiltersViewControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
  func controller(_ controller: FilterViewController,
                  didSelectCategory jewelry: Bool,
                  hat: Bool,
                  shoe: Bool,
                  gear: Bool,
                  apparel: Bool)
}
```

And call it

```
@IBAction func acceptSelections(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.controller(self,
                         didSelectCategory: jewelryBtn.isSelected,
                         hat: hatBtn.isSelected,
                         shoe: shoeBtn.isSelected,
                         gear: gearBtn.isSelected,
                         apparel: apparelBtn.isSelected)
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

It seems to be a multiple choice selection so you have to combine the options in the query.

Comment: it works, but now im getting all sorts of errors in my ```extension HomeViewController: FiltersViewControllerDelegate{``` with the same error being Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool', which I am getting in every single if statement

Comment: Of course you do, the type has changed and all values are non-optional so you can get rid of the optional bindings. You have to adjust the method.